# Default Persistent Layout In Laravel + Inertia + Vite

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-vite

In the previous way of setting up inertia in a laravel app, I could tweak the resolve property in the `createInertiaApp function from:

```
{
   ...,
   resolve: name => import("./Pages/${name}"),
   ...
}
```

To

```
{
   ...,
   resolve: name => {
    const page = require("./Pages/${name}").default
    if(!page.layout) {
     page.layout = DefaultLayoutFile
    }
   },
   ...
}
```

To allow me manually pass a default layout file to be used in pages.

But with Vite becoming the default asset bundler and according to [the docs](https://laravel-vite.dev/guide/extra-topics/inertia.html#overview-1), I must use a `resolvePageComponent` function which takes in `import.meta.glob` as a second argument to instruct Vite which files to bundle.

Problem here is the import gets returned from this `resolvePageComponent` so I cannot access the default object like I normally will from a require function.

So I have not been able to attach a default layout file to imported pages.

Has anyone been able to find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming you imported your default layout file like this (remember to not use @ in imports anymore as only relative paths work for static analysis reasons):

`import DefaultLayoutFile from './Layouts/DefaultLayoutFile.vue'`

You can use the following code to get default layout working with Inertia and Vite:

```js
  resolve: (name) => {
    const page = resolvePageComponent(
      `./Pages/${name}.vue`,
      import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue")
    );
    page.then((module) => {
      module.default.layout = module.default.layout || DefaultLayoutFile;
    });
    return page;
  },
```

**[UPDATE 2022-08-01]**

Since this is still receiving views, I though it would be useful to show how to get the `@` working in imports in Vite.

Require `path` below your imports in `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
const path = require('path')
```

And then add `resolve` into your config below:

```
export default defineConfig({
  resolve:{
    alias:{
      '@' : path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    },
  },
})
```

Now `@` will point to your Laravel root and you can import components dynamically from anywhere:

*For example* `import LayoutTop from '@/Layouts/LayoutTop.vue'`
*will now point to*
`/resources/js/Layouts/LayoutTop.vue`

Remember that Vite needs the `.vue` extension when importing Vue SFC files.

Comment: I've refactored this a bit to use async/await which makes the resolve function look a lot shorter (3 lines).

Comment: how is your code? @PieterJan

Comment: I tried this with Svelte and it's not working.

Comment: It's worth to mention that _"... the Laravel Vite plugin automatically adds an @ alias for your /resources/js directory."_. See [here](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#importing-your-css-from-your-javascript-entry-points)

Answer (score 6):

The async await version of the accepted answer

```
resolve: async name => {
    const page = await resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue"));
    page.default.layout ??= DefaultLayoutFile;
    return page;
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

@residualflash Adding condition works as well:

```
resolve: async name => {
 const page = await resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue"));
 if (name.startsWith('Auth/')){
  page.default.layout ??= AuthLayoutFile;
 }else{
  page.default.layout ??= DefaultLayoutFile;
 }
 return page;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

For Default Persistent Layout in Laravel+ Vue3 + Inertia + Vite Setup(Laravel 9 and above)

// resources\js\app.js

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => {
    const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', { eager: true })
    return pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .mount(el)
  },
})
```

Change to

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

// import your default layout.vue,@~resources\js
import Layout from '@/Layouts/Front/Layout.vue'

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => {
    const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', { eager: true })

    // New code added
    let page = pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`].default
    
    if(!page.layout){
      page.layout=Layout;
    }
    // OR
    // page.layout??=Layout;

    return pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .mount(el)
  },
})
```

---

For Default Persistent Layout in Laravel+ Vue3 + Inertia + Webpack Setup(Laravel 8 and below)

// resources\js\app.js

```
createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
})
```

Change to

```
// import your default layout.vue
import Layout from './Layouts/Front/Layout.vue'
createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => {
  let page=require(`./Pages/${name}`).default;

    if(!page.layout){
      page.layout=Layout;
    }
    // OR
    // page.layout??=Layout;

    return page;
 },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked from me using the [vite with inertia preset](https://laravel-vite.dev/guide/extra-topics/inertia.html)

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'vite-plugin-laravel/inertia'
import DefaultLayout from '@/views/layouts/default.vue'
import SimpleLayout from '@/views/layouts/simple.vue'
import UserLayout from '@/views/layouts/user.vue'

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => {
        const page = resolvePageComponent(
            name,
            import.meta.glob('../views/pages/**/*.vue'),
            DefaultLayout
        );

        page.then((module) => {
            if (name.startsWith('auth.')) module.layout = SimpleLayout;
            if (name.startsWith('user.')) module.layout = [DefaultLayout, UserLayout];
        });

        return page
    },
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mount(el)
    },
})
```

Comment: I believe `module.__file` won't be available in production, I ran into that issue a few weeks back. Better to check if `name` includes `'/auth/'` instead.

Granted, that issue did occur when using Laravel Mix, not Vite.

Comment: Your right i had to refactor it to work in production. I set the default layout in resolvePageComponent and then conditionally changed the layout based on the name.